# Display "product short description" on WooCommerce admin order items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, product

I want to display "product short description" in the "edit order" page below the product title in admin.

[image]

---

I am relatively new to WooCommerce and from what I have found I believe I should make use of the `woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta` action hook

Like:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 'short_discription', 10, 2 );
function short_discription(  ) {

}
```

---

Any help on how to adjust this further would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed using the correct hook, but you have access to **3** passed arguments (opposite 2). Namely: `$item_id`, `$item` & `$product`

**Note:** Because a variable product can only have 1 product short description, so all product variations would have exactly the same description. You can display the **product variation description** instead of **product short description** for variable products

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta( $item_id, $item, $product ) {
    // Targeting line items type only
    if ( $item->get_type() !== 'line_item' ) return;
    
    // Variable 
    if ( $product->get_type() == 'variation' ) {
        // Get the variable product description
        $description = $product->get_description();     
    } else {
        // Get product short desciption
        $description = $product->get_short_description();       
    }
    
    // Isset & NOT empty
    if ( isset ( $description ) && ! empty( $description ) ) {
        echo $description;
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 'action_woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 10, 3 );
```

---

Result:

[image]